# Owl Carousel mobile view customization

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm using "owl carousel" for my one page slider. I have made it always to be shown two items. The thing is that on mobile view I want the items to be stacked one under another not inline horizontally as the default settings. Do you know how I can achieve this?
This is my code:

```
          <div class="slide slide4">
        <div class="text-item">
          <div class="heading">
            <h1>Power Ups</h1>
            <p>The game offers you two very powerful power ups.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="owl-demo-power" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item power1">
              <img src="../assets/images/game/power1.png">
              <p>Use the “Bubble Shield” to protect your next bubble from 2 enemies. The enemies are stunned for few seconds.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="item power2">
              <img src="../assets/images/game/power2.png">
              <p>Use the “Bubble Shield” to protect your next bubble from 2 enemies. The enemies are stunned for few seconds.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And the initialization:

```
$("#owl-demo-power").owlCarousel({
  autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
  items : 2,
  itemsDesktop : false,
  itemsDesktopSmall : [1200,2],
  itemsTablet: [768,2],
  autoPlay:  false
});
```

Also, the basic css for the carousel items:

```
#owl-demo .owl-item {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#owl-demo .slide4 .item {
    margin: 50px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#owl-demo .slide4 .item img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your `css` aswell?

Comment: I have updated my question with the css example:)